# Android receives empty notification one some devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm using firebase for push notifications delivering and it works fine. But on some devices receives 2 notifications: 1st is good, but second looks like this. The main problem is that there is no way that my NotificationCompat.Builder has created 2nd, because it has constant contenttitle and 2nd notification has no title (yeah I can't debug, because it works good on all my devices). What can be the reason of this bag? [image]

Comment: this is Xiaomi, android 6

Comment: I'm not sure it's a problem related to Firebase, I've also seen it related to GCM. So.. i think it's a problem of Xiaomi's distribution